# Joomla 2.5, emailing contacts

Tags: forms, joomla, contacts

I have a Joomla site (www.newingtonscouting.com) where my customers want a single page where anyone can send an email to  multiple contacts (scoutmasters) whose names they don't know.  I already have those contacts in a single contact category.

Is there a way to do this?  I need something relatively simple for when/if this gets handed to the customer to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this using the standard Joomla contact system, as it only supports sending an e-mail to a single contact. You'll need to use another extension for this. Here is a list on the JED site that you can choose from:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms

Do bare in mind, not all of them will support e-mailing to multiple contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You could  do a plugin to override the contact form adding a bcc field, but wouldn't it be easier to do and maintain just to make them a single email address that would forward to them?